# How to get a record using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE?

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

I have a bunch of functions with signatures like:

```
FUNCTION func1 (par1 IN VARCHAR2, par2 IN NUMBER) RETURN my_rec;
```

and I have a function for retrieving data from this bunch of functions:

```
FUNCTION get_result (func_name IN VARCHAR2, par1 IN VARCHAR2, par2 IN NUMBER) RETURN my_rec;
IS
    rec1 my_rec;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || func_name || '(:par1, :par2) FROM DUAL'
    INTO rec1
    USING IN par1, IN par2;

    RETURN rec1;
END;
```

but this code fails with ORA-01007 'variable not in select list'.
How can I rewrite statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all works fine for me (Oracle 10G), one I correct the syntax error in your function definition (the unwanted semi-colon on the first line):

```
SQL> create type my_rec is object (id integer, name varchar2(30))
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create FUNCTION func1 (par1 IN VARCHAR2, par2 IN NUMBER) RETURN my_rec
  2  is
  3    l_rec my_rec := my_rec (1, 'x');
  4  begin
  5     return l_rec;
  6  end;
  7  /


Function created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  FUNCTION get_result (func_name IN VARCHAR2, par1 IN VARCHAR2, par2 IN NUMBER) RETURN my_rec
  3  IS
  4      rec1 my_rec;
  5  BEGIN
  6      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || func_name || '(:par1, :par2) FROM DUAL'
  7      INTO rec1
  8      USING IN par1, IN par2;
  9      RETURN rec1;
 10  END;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select get_result ('func1',1,2) from dual;

GET_RESULT('FUNC1',1,2)(ID, NAME)
-------------------------------------------------
MY_REC(1, 'x')
```

Comment: it works when I define my_rec as an object type, but doesn't work when my_rec defined as a record type in package. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @negr-o, a record type in a package is only known within PL/SQL, you can't use it in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can concatenate to the query like you did with *func_name*.

Comment: what did you mean: concatenate values of variables with dynamic-sql string instead of using 'USING' clause?

Comment: Yes. I admit this is a security hole just in the case that par1 and par2 are not "safe" strings.